# Figure inside tabular environment

Tags: tables, graphics, floats

First question out here, i'm using the code below to fix a company logo below my time there centered, and at the same time fix the text at the same level of the experience duration, like on the third image.

Can anyone help me with this? Thanks in advance

My code

```
    \documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
    \usepackage{marvosym}
    \usepackage{fontspec}               
    \usepackage{xunicode,xltxtra,url,parskip} 
    \RequirePackage{color,graphicx}
    \usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor}
    \usepackage[big]{layaureo}          
    \usepackage{fullpage}
    \usepackage{titlesec}
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    \definecolor{linkcolour}{rgb}{0,0.2,0.6}
    \hypersetup{colorlinks,breaklinks,urlcolor=linkcolour,     linkcolor=linkcolour}
    \defaultfontfeatures{Mapping=tex-text}
    \setmainfont[
    SmallCapsFont = Fontin-SmallCaps.otf,
    BoldFont = Fontin-Bold.otf,
    ItalicFont = Fontin-Italic.otf
    ]{Fontin.otf}
    \titleformat{\section}{\Large\scshape\raggedright}{}{0em}{}[\titlerule]
    \titlespacing{\section}{0pt}{3pt}{3pt}
    \hyphenation{im-pre-se}
    \usepackage[absolute]{textpos}
    \setlength{\TPHorizModule}{30mm}
    \setlength{\TPVertModule}{\TPHorizModule}
    \textblockorigin{2mm}{0.8\paperheight}
    \setlength{\parindent}{0pt}
    \usepackage{anysize}
    \marginsize{0,5cm}{0,5cm}{0,5cm}{0,5cm}
    \usepackage{float}

    \newcommand{\commentOut}[1]{}
    \newcommand\tab[1][1cm]{\hspace*{#1}}

    \begin{document}

    %SECTION: Work Experience at the top
    {\color{RawSienna}\section{Experiência Profissional}}
    \begin{tabular}{r|p{16cm}}
    \textsc{Mar 2017-Actual}
    \\
    \includegraphics[width=1cm]{inventors.png}

    & Monitor e Envolvimento de Cliente em \textsc{The Inventors},  Almada 
    \\
    &\footnotesize{Tenho duas missões na The Inventors. A primeira    baseia-se em garantir apoio e ensinar conceitos básicos científicos, de várias disciplinas, às crianças que frequentam os nossos ateliers. A segunda consiste em envolver os clientes, ou potenciais clientes, abordando a nossa missão, filosofia e os nossos serviços.}
    \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} 

    \\
    \textsc{Nov 2016-Actual} 
    & Campus Ambassador em \textsc{Spark Agency}, Lisboa 
    \\
    &\footnotesize{No desempenho das minhas funções como Embaixador Spark sou responsável por ser a go-to-person no meu campus, no que toca a young talent engagement e relação com empresas, ao mesmo tempo que promovo a marca da própria Spark e um dos seus principais eventos ao nível universitário conhecido como Pitch Bootcamp fazendo com que se torne no melhor acelerador de carreiras do Mundo.}
    \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} 
    \\

    \end{document}
```

My try and another example with the role description aligned with "Nov 2016 - Actual" but without the logo below. 
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please edit your posting to show the actual code, rather than a screenshot of the code.

Comment: A separate comment: `\footnotesize` is a switch; it doesn't take an argument.

Comment: @Mico thanks for the warning. About '\footnotesize' I think the problem is not there, since it only changes the role description font size in this case

Comment: @rfr.ferreira, your code is not possible to compile! Please, complete it with `\documentclass{...}`, preamble with essential packages for your problem and on its end add `end{document}` ...

Comment: @Zarko Sorry again, I'll add it right away. I know it's not an excuse, but it's my first time posting here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've had to guess many of the document parameters. Hopefully, the settings embedded in the following answer aren't too unrealistic.

The main thing I'd like to suggest is that you encase the directive `\textsc{Mar 2017--Actual}` and the graphic in a single-column `tabular` environment and that you encase this `tabular` environment in a `\smash` directive, effectively making it a zero-height and zero-depth object.

[image]

```
\documentclass[demo]{article} % remove 'demo' option in real document
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[a4paper,textwidth=18cm]{geometry} % set suitable textblock parameters
\usepackage{tabularx}

\begin{document}

\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{@{}r|X@{}}
    \smash{\begin{tabular}[t]{@{}r@{}}
    \textsc{Mar 2017--Actual}\\
    \includegraphics[width=1cm,height=1cm]{inventors.png}
    \end{tabular}}
    & Monitor e Envolvimento de Cliente em \textsc{The Inventors},  Almada \\
    &\footnotesize Tenho duas missões na The Inventors. A primeira    baseia-se em garantir apoio e ensinar conceitos básicos científicos, de várias disciplinas, às crianças que frequentam os nossos ateliers. A segunda consiste em envolver os clientes, ou potenciais clientes, abordando a nossa missão, filosofia e os nossos serviços. \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
    \textsc{Nov 2016--Actual} 
    & Campus Ambassador em \textsc{Spark Agency}, Lisboa \\
    &\footnotesize No desempenho das minhas funções como Embaixador Spark sou responsável por ser a go-to-person no meu campus, no que toca a young talent engagement e relação com empresas, ao mesmo tempo que promovo a marca da própria Spark e um dos seus principais eventos ao nível universitário conhecido como Pitch Bootcamp fazendo com que se torne no melhor acelerador de carreiras do Mundo. \\
    \multicolumn{2}{c}{} \\
\end{tabularx}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks! It work perfectly, but know I'm having trouble centering the figure below the text, instead of being close to that bar, I'm trying to put the centered at the text "Mar 2017 -- Actual".

Thanks again!